# PHP cURL loading delay

Tags: php, curl

My problem is, I need to cURL-load a page that uses Ajax-based search, to get results of that search. And I need to organize a delay between `curl_exec()` and value returning. In other words, I need to execute `curl_exec()` for no less than 5 seconds. `sleep()` seems to stop curl execution and does not work.
Will greatly appreciate any hint or clue

**UPD**
I don't know how, but on this page http://vkontakte.ru/gsearch.php?section=video&q=sample&name=1, but it requires an account to access curl DOES capture the search made by ajax. But if page tooks too long to load, Ajax returns `"action was too fast"` error. So I just need to prolong curl execution. Sorry if being unclear.

Answer (score 1):

Curl is unable to capture ajax request. Maybe you can proxify the response with a Python script that use webkit module ? ( https://trac.webkit.org/wiki/PythonGuidelines )

Comment: Flyingswissman's answer is correct, and so is this one. However, this one suggests a possible and interesting solution.

Comment: Sorry, but it seems too complicated. Interesting though :)

Answer (score 0):

Use [FireBug](http://getfirebug.com/) (see Net tab) or other tool to capture the Ajax request and just Curl the request data instead.

Comment: Thanks, i'll try it. But I really hope that one can do something with curl only.

Answer (score 0):

When you curl a page you will get the html response. Any change javascript would make to the html is not made by waiting any amount of time- its a change made by the browser.

What you can try to do is find the code-snipped that makes the information request inside your html (as mentioned by Serg ikS using FireBug ). And then make a second curl-load.

Some websites make these requests as cryptic as possible to prevent screen scraping information- so it may not be that easy.

Hope that helps.

**UPDATE**

I tried to reproduce your error without success. I can login and the html displays all the results... Only thing I notice is that it executes pretty slow sometimes.

Here I parsed all the search results (using php /cURL):

(click to enlarge)
[image]

Comment: Oh, thanks for so much dedicaion. Well, my problem is that it executes pretty slow, exactly :) If you try to load next search result and previous not loaded yet, that error occurs. Big thanks for such interest in my problem.

Comment: So if it is no way to delay curl execution, i'll stick to solution of parsing by small bits and rewriting it with FireBug in future :) Thanks

Comment: hmm, maybe there is a limit for the number of server request per unit time.. per ip.

Comment: how many searches do you need to make? I mean will you constantly be indexing in a loop? or just one request per page? As I still cant reproduce the error. If its just slow then you could do a cronjob which regularly caches your scraped data in a database.